# Is there a way to run a micronaut app on 2 different ports

Tags: port, micronaut

I'm using the Micronaut framework to build a Java app, mvc style.

Now in my controller, instead of exposing two routes
`/route/buyer`
and
`/route/seller`

I'd like to have only one route:
`/route/` but exposed on two different ports, one port will be reserved for the buyer and the other for the sellers.

This is for convenience so the port used by the seller can be blocked/unblocked at the network level

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `port` value on the `@Controller`.

Ex:

```java
@Controller(value = "/route", port = "8081")
public class SellerController {

    @Get
    String get() {
        return "Seller Controller (port: 8081)";
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller("/route")
public class BuyerController {

    @Get
    String get() {
        return "Buyer Controller (port: 8080)";
    }
}
```

```
% curl localhost:8081/route
Seller Controller (port: 8081)

% curl localhost:8080/route
Buyer Controller (port: 8080)
```